# Python - Sistema Multiplayer Local

Tags: python, windows, cliente-servidor, servidor

Estou tentando criar um sistema de multiplayer local, onde terá um script para o "servidor" e vários "clientes" poderão se conectar. Por enquanto vou usar em uma aplicação de teste simples, onde os usuários criarão suas contas, farão login e na tela de cada usuário que estiver conectado aparecerá a lista de todos que estiverem conectados. A lista seria alterada em todos os clientes quando algum usuário logasse ou saísse.

Do jeito que eu estava fazendo, quando o cliente queria fazer alguma ação, como login por exemplo, ele gravava uma string em um arquivo de texto, por exemplo 'login usuario senha'. Daí tinha o script do server que ficava em um loop infinito lendo todos esses arquivos (cada cliente aberto seria 1, não necessariamente o usuário conectado) e gravando no mesmo arquivo a resposta, por exemplo:

Arquivo de texto:

```
client_request:login usertest 1234
server_answer:wrong_password
```

Só que estava lento, com alguns problemas e acho meio gambiarra ficar gravando e lendo arquivos de texto sem parar. Queria alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso de uma maneira melhor, sem usar arquivos !

Se não fui claro tento explicar de novo.

Answer (score 1):

O mais usual nesses caso é usar uma conexão de sockets - mesmo com o cliente e o servidor estando na mesma máquina. Uma grande vantagem que você tem é que o mesmo programa vai funcionar para clientes e servidores na mesma máquina, mas também com clientes em máquinas remotas.

Bom... para descrever a ideia de funcionamento e toda a implementação de sockets, e como você poderia fazer, daria para encher um livro. :-) e aliás, existem bons livros sobre isso. Explicando de forma  simples uma conexão usando sockets faz justamente o que você quer: o programa cliente chama o servidor, e envia uma série de dados para ele - e em seguida recebe uma série de dados de volta.

Em termos práticos, para fins de exercícios - e não para um programa final, você pode querer usar o módulo "socket" do Python - na documentação da linguagem tem um bom tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html

Claro que aí você vai cair em um problema que não está 100% resolvido mesmo com mais de 40 anos de gente trabalhando em cima:  como o seu programa espera  e escuta conexões de novos clientes e mesmo assim responde aos clientes que já conectaram. Daí existem diversas abordagens possíveis - uma seria usar threads e uma thread para cada conexão. Ou múltiplos processos. Ou micro-threads. Ao longo dos últimos anos, a abordagem mais favorecida tem sido o uso de prooramação assíncrona p'ra isso - se você estiver usando Python 3.4, pode ver o módulo asyncio - em outras versões do Python, há o projeto externo "trollius" que faz isso.

**Link Úteis**

[Mesma pergunta no SO Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227722/creating-a-multiplayer-game-in-python)

[Tutorial Sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html)